# How can I tell blender to catch up changes I made in an own python module?

Tags: python, blender

I set up a Scripts folder in the preferences underneath which I created a `modules` directory with a file `my_module.py`.

In blender's text editor I'm importing this with

```
from my_module import *
```

Up to here it's working fine.
However, whenever I perform changes to the `my_module.py`, which I'm doing in an external editor to have full flexibility, I have to quit blender and start it again for the changes to take effect.

Is there any way to tell blender that it detects changes in modules I import so I don't have to quit and restart all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is Python3:
You can use the `reload` method from `importlib` library.

```
from importlib import reload
reload(my_module)
```

This will reload the contents of the module. But with that you cannot import the way you are importing your module, i.e. you won't be able to do `from my_module import *`. You will have to import your module like `import my_module` and to reload it later you can do it by just doing `reload(my_module)`. In case doing this causes inconvenience for typing the module name again and again, remember tab key is your friend for completion

In case of Python2, reload() method is already present and you don't do `from importlib import reload`

Comment: Ok, since I'm not a python Guru, I achieved it with `import my_module` and `from my_module import *` plus the reload. there is no tab completion in blender and flooding my code with module names doesn't make it more readable.

Comment: What still feels strange is that I have to put the reload into the actual code file. That's not what you would expect in a programming language (load this module and reload it if it changed). Imagine you have a bunch of modules and you have to always tell "and please reload...".

Comment: Once blender imports the module it is compiled and kept  in memory, reload removes the existing copy and re-compiles the module. As shown in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28505/935) you can wrap it in `if 'bpy' in locals()` to test whether to import or reload, you will find [official addons](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/add_advanced_objects_menu/__init__.py) use this method.